# GCE Protocol Forwarding, use IP for outgoing requests

Tags: routing, ip, google-cloud-platform

I have a GCE instance that has multiple [protocol-forwarding rules](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding/) to it.

All the forwards work prefectly, but when the instance creates a request from itself to the internet, how do I specify which ip address to use when doing, for example, a wget from the instance?

Answer (score 1):

You can add IP addresses of forwarding rules to the network interface and then configure using iptables setup Source Network Address Translation (SNAT) to change the source IP address of your outgoing traffic.

Example:

- IP address of forwarding rule: `A.B.C.D`
- Add this IP to your network interface (sub-interface):

  Open interface file

  ```
  $ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
  ```

  Add these lines and save it

  ```
  auto eth0:0
  allow-hotplug eth0:0
  iface eth0:0 inet static
  address A.B.C.D
  netmask 255.255.255.255
  ```
- Restart the networking service

  ```
  $ sudo service networking restart
  ```
- Create an iptables SNAT rule:

  ```
  $ sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -d DES_IPs -j SNAT --to A.B.C.D
  ```